# Kibana - how do I display stack bar data when I have rows containing a type and a count

Tags: logstash, kibana

Kibana - how do I display stack bar data when I have rows containing a type and a count

Sample data:

```
12:00 type1 10
12:00 type2 20
12:01 type1 12
12:01 type2 25
```

I'd like a stack bar chart that shows two stacked columns (type1 and type2 on top of each other), with time on the x axis and the count (i.e. 20) on the y axis

Seems logstash/kibana prefers to do the counting itself (i.e. counting ten rows of type1 in the log file). Any way to force it to use my count column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a histogram, and in "Panel > Values" settings, set the "Chart Value" to "total" and the "Value Field" to the field containing the counts

What remains is how to get the chart to automatically include new types (if type3 turns up in the logs, for example).

Comment: I just found out that my previous comment about not being able to do it was wrong.  If you are running kibana 3.1, just click on the green circle next to the query and change the top selection box from lucene to topN and then choose the top 5 or however many you have.

Comment: Alcanzar - this is a step forward. I wonder how we could get the topN to use the counts that exist in the data?